# Button with Image and Text vertically aligned using autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I m very new to IOS development and AutoLayout .
I am facing issues to align the Image and Text inside UIbutton using Storyboard. I had tried to achieve it with TitleEdgeinset and ImageEdge insets accordingly to place the Title ( text ) vertically centered below the Image. But the issue is I have 3 similar buttons which are Vertically stacked ( StackView) and the Text is dynamically set since we have localized strings ( includes Arabic rtl ) . 
The image and text moves according to the text length. Is there any ways that I can achieve to make all the buttons with image and text vertically alligned.Also, different screen resolutions are not currently working if using edge insets. Appreciate your help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using storyboard? Or is this all programatic?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention , its using storyboard

Comment: I would create a custom view class that has one UIImageView and one UILabel, setup the constraints in that custom view, then use that custom view in your main view controller, set the three custom view's `centerY` to have multiplication factor of 0.25 (25%), 0.5 (50%) and 0.75 (75%) of the view controller view's `Bottom` property.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Few days ago, I solved similar problem,try this

```
 private func adjustImageAndTitleOffsetsForButton (button: UIButton) {

    let spacing: CGFloat = 6.0

    let imageSize = button.imageView!.frame.size

    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -imageSize.width, -(imageSize.height + spacing), 0)

    let titleSize = button.titleLabel!.frame.size

    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(titleSize.height + spacing), 0, 0, -titleSize.width)
}
```

call this method for each button, like

```
self.adjustImageAndTitleOffsetsForButton(yourButton)
```

Comment: How does this match "*autolayout constraints*"?

Comment: i cleaned it up as an extension and no forced unwraps
 
```func adjustImageAndTitleOffsetsForButton (spacing: CGFloat = 6.0) {

        guard let label = titleLabel, let img = imageView else { return }

        let imageSize = img.frame.size
        
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -imageSize.width, bottom: -
(imageSize.height + spacing), right: 0)
        
        let titleSize = label.frame.size

        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -titleSize.width)
    
    }```

Comment: The best place to put this code is `layoutSubviews` function. As it automatically will handle image and text changes.

Comment: `let titleSize = button.titleLabel!.frame.size` change to `let titleSize = button.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize` , can avoid text size problem

Answer (score 4):

Combining Ajay's and Matej's answer:

[image: UIButton with vertically aligned image and text]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class VerticalButton: UIButton {
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    centerButtonImageAndTitle()
}

private func centerButtonImageAndTitle() {
    let titleSize = self.titleLabel?.frame.size ?? .zero
    let imageSize = self.imageView?.frame.size  ?? .zero
    let spacing: CGFloat = 6.0
    self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing),left: 0, bottom: 0, right:  -titleSize.width)
    self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -imageSize.width, bottom: -(imageSize.height + spacing), right: 0)
 }
}
```

Comment: contentHorizontalAlignment should be center if you want to have the button laid out correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iOS 15.0 you can use:

```
// Create a button
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        
// Configure the button using UIButton.Configuration
var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
config.titlePadding = 10
config.imagePlacement = .top // this is whats makes the magic
config.imagePadding = 10
button.configuration = config
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified [Ajay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34682893/611879) because my images weren't centered:

```
func centerButtonImageAndTitle(button: UIButton) {
  let spacing: CGFloat = 5
  let titleSize = button.titleLabel!.frame.size
  let imageSize = button.imageView!.frame.size

  button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -imageSize.width, bottom: -(imageSize.height + spacing), right: 0)
  button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: -imageSize.width/2, bottom: 0, right: -titleSize.width)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that worked for me. Just set the button class to `HorizontallyCenteredButton` in storyboard and set the title and image top and bottom insets according to your needs (to place the image higher than title) and the button will adjust horizontal insets automatically so that the image is centered above title.

```
class HorizontallyCenteredButton: LocalizedButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.centerButtonImageAndTitle()
    }

    func centerButtonImageAndTitle() {
        let size = self.bounds.size
        let titleSize = self.titleLabel!.frame.size
        let imageSize = self.imageView!.frame.size

        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.imageEdgeInsets.top, left: size.width/2 - imageSize.width/2, bottom: self.imageEdgeInsets.bottom, right: 0)
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.titleEdgeInsets.top, left: -imageSize.width + size.width/2 - titleSize.width/2, bottom: self.titleEdgeInsets.bottom, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To align all the buttons vertically, first select the buttons, then click the button on the bottom-right of the storyboard titled "Align", and finally select "Vertical Centers" in the menu that appears. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thats been already done . The issue is to align the image and text vertically center of the button. And all the 3 buttons with the images should be aligned as center. But now if the text is been dynamic and varied length so the image allignment goes for a toss.

Comment: @user2695433: Then all you should need to do is make the size of your button a little larger and set the text to be centered. You may have to use attributed text to do so on a button.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Button with vertical image and text]

I created a view, then put a VStack with image and text, as well as button.
Make sure the VStack constraints are 0 on all 4 sides so it covers the button :)

Answer (score -1):

this is an easy one, so apologies if you have already tried it!

you don't need to set anything for insets, just make sure that the 3 buttons are aligned with horizontal centres ...
[image: Add New Alignment Constraints]

select the controls you want to align, and click on the button highlighted below (bottom right on the xCode screen) and select the Vertical Centres option to align the three with each other, or select Horizontally in Container to put them in the middle of your view.

Comment: Thanks Russel , got it